# Attempting to read entire file only gets me one line

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read and write data in Java for Android. I can supposedly read and write, but when I read the file, I can only get the first line. I don't understand why.

Here's my code for writing to the file.

```
                    try {
                        System.out.println(currentTime);
                        System.out.println(currentLocation);   
                         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("history", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
                         bw.write(currentTransaction + " " + currentTime + " " + currentLocation + "\n");
                         bw.close();
                        }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                         System.out.println("Error in Writing To History File");
                        }
```

And here's my code for reading the file.

```
            BufferedReader in;
            String totalHistory = null;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String strLine;

            try {
                 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("history")));
                 //totalHistory = in.readLine();
                 //while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                //   stringBuffer.append(strLine);
                //   System.out.println("HERES A THING");
                 //    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
                  //   stringBuffer.append("\n");
                //   totalHistory = stringBuffer.toString();


                     //String[] tokens = strLine.split("|");
                     //totalHistory = totalHistory + tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1] + " " + tokens[2] + " " + tokens[4];
                // }
                 totalHistory = in.readLine();
                 System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
                 in.close();
                }
            catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.out.println("Error in Reading History.");
                }
```

As you can see, I have a lot of commented out code in there. I've tried a lot of stuff, so I wanted to leave it there so I could show you guys what I've previously tried. Here's what my console shows me from the System.outs I've written.

```
01-16 13:32:15.473: I/System.out(1620): We can read/write.
01-16 13:32:15.473: I/System.out(1620): Read File Successfully
01-16 13:32:15.473: I/System.out(1620): null
01-16 13:32:15.473: I/System.out(1620): null
01-16 13:32:18.553: I/System.out(1620): Read Balance File Successfully
01-16 13:32:18.553: I/System.out(1620): 0.00
01-16 13:32:18.553: I/System.out(1620): 0.00
01-16 13:32:18.563: I/System.out(1620): 16/01/14 13:32:18
01-16 13:32:18.563: I/System.out(1620): Longitude: -76.13065846 Latitude: 36.78333427
01-16 13:32:21.233: I/System.out(1620): Read Balance File Successfully
01-16 13:32:21.233: I/System.out(1620): 11.00
01-16 13:32:21.233: I/System.out(1620): 11.00
01-16 13:32:21.243: I/System.out(1620): 16/01/14 13:32:21
01-16 13:32:21.243: I/System.out(1620): Longitude: -76.13065846 Latitude: 36.78333427
01-16 13:32:21.593: D/ViewRootImpl(1620): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-16 13:32:21.693: E/ViewRootImpl(1620): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-16 13:32:22.283: D/ViewRootImpl(1620): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

As you can see, it's supposedly recording both instances, but only READING one of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `in.readLine()` does? Why do you think so? What do you think you're printing by using `System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());`? Why do you think so?

Comment: I only see one `in.readLine()` and not in a loop of sorts.. so therefore... only one line is read.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that I had forgotten to write it in a loop. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's writing out properly btw, just open up the resulting file to check. But besides that, you can do this to read entire files:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String str = null;
while((str = reader.readLine()) != null) builder.append(str+"\n");
String endString = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to go with this, but nothing seems to have changed, making me think that perhaps its also a problem with writing out properly. How would I find the file in question, since it's on the phone and not the IDE?

Comment: See, you're using the write() method... which I believe just writes a new file with the given name. Thus, it overwrites your file every time you write out. I would use append, flush*, and close. But to check the file, I would find something at the play store. I have an application like that, but my phone is dead and can't get it for ya, and I'm not staying online long. :P

Answer (score -1):

You have used the `readLine` function only once. Use it like this:

```
try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("history");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }
```